# What is a good alternative for “stand in”?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a sentence that currently reads: The question "What do you do" can be a proxy for a person's value.

I'm sure that *proxy* doesn't fit but I'm trying to find a way to say that a person's position is wrongfully used as a way to confer value.

Comment: *Proxy* may work, or you could use any synonym for *euphemism*.  But I don't think this sentence will work, even with a different word there.  The question ("what do you do") doesn't stand in for the value, it's used to assess the value.  You could restructure like this: "The question 'what do you do' can be a polite way of asking 'how much value should I assign to you?'" Or, ditching the "question" language: "We ask a person what they do so that we can assess the person's value."

Comment: This question is somewhat relevant: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/530410/word-for-using-a-child-spokesman-rather-than-an-adult-because-opponents-wont-at

Comment: And this: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185085/word-for-a-person-being-used

Answer (score -1):

The question "what do you do" can implicitly be construed as a superficial measure to judge a person's value.

Comment: Perhaps a person’s ***answer*** to the question can be used that way...